# Проблема с файлом ресурсов Недопустимый файл Resx. .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

При добавлении файла ресурсов в папку Resources/Controllers и попытки ребилда проекта вылетает следущая ошибка:

```
HomeController.en.resx: [MSB3103] Недопустимый файл Resx. Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: destinationIndex
```

сам файл HomeController.en.resx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
</resheader>
<resheader name="version">
    <value>1.3</value>
</resheader>
<resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</resheader>
<resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</resheader>
```

файл HomeController.en.Designer.cs:

```
namespace Web.Resources.Controllers {
using System;
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
public class HomeController_en {

    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal HomeController_en() {
    }


    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Web.Resources.Controllers.HomeController.en", typeof(HomeController_en).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }


    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
        get {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился переходом на Visual Studio 2017